# Android - ImageView: setImageBitmap VS setImageDrawable

Tags: android, imageview, android-bitmap

What is the difference between `setImageBitmap` and `setImageDrawable`?

I have an image which I would like to set dynamically from file. The tutorial that I followed says to convert my `Bitmap` to a `BitmapDrawable` then set it using `setImageDrawable`. I've notice that setting the `Bitmap` directly with `setImageBitmap` also works but I don't notice any difference.

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(image);
imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

OR

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Comment: I think no difference in these concrete two examples

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There is no difference between the two internally `setImageBitmap` is calling `setImageDrawable`.

Below code is picked from *ImageView.java* of AOSP

```
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    // if this is used frequently, may handle bitmaps explicitly
    // to reduce the intermediate drawable object
    setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bm));
}
```

Comment: +1 for looking at the Android source. One of the benefits of open source stuff.

Comment: The difference is between the new BitmapDrawable(Resource, Bitmap) and the deprecated constructor new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap). If you are using the deprecated one a layout problem can happen.

Comment: I disagree with the conclusion so. There is a difference : if you want to optimize a list view with images for instance, you would be better creating a Drawable outiside of the UI Thread and assign it to each imageview in the UI thread. If you use a Bitmap, then the creation of the Drawable will slow down the UI thread and the list won't scroll as fast & smooth.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, you may see the difference, if you sometimes use `null` as an argument:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable(); // d == null

imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable(); // d == some BitmapDrawable, != null
```

so if you are checking for existence of a drawable in `ImageView`, beware of it.

Comment: THIS is the most important distinction, thank you for this. I like to use the ImageView's logic for checking if it's set, so this works great.

Answer (score 14):

I just wrote up an article for this. Wish to be able to answer your question.

https://plus.google.com/112740367348600290235/posts/VNAfFLDcKrw

`ImageView` has 4 APIs to specify the image. Which one to use? What is the difference?

1. setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)
2. setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
3. setImageResource(int resId)
4. setImageURI(URI uri)

`ImageView`, by the name, is used to display an image. But what is a image? A `Bitmap` is-a image, not hard to understand and we use `setImageBitmap` for that purpose. However, internally, the `ImageView` has-a `Drawable` but not a `Bitmap` and that is what `setImageDrawable` for. When you call `setImageBitmap`, internally, first the bitmap will be wrapped to `BitmapDrawable`, which IS-A `Drawable`, and then call `setImageDrawable`.

Here is the code.

```
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bm));
}
```

So, what about the 3 and 4 API?

You should already know that that are bunches of ways to create a bitmap: from a file path, from an input stream, from the Uri, or from the resource file.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String pathName)
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(Inputstream)
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resource res, int id)
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte[] data)
```

Aware of this, it is easy to understand `setImageResource`/`setImageUri` is just same as `setImageBitmap`.

To sum up, `setImageDrawable` is the primitive function other APIs rely on. The other 3 are just helper methods making you write less code.

In addition, it is very important to keep in mind that `ImageView` actually has-a `Drawable`, which not necessarily to be a `BitmapDrawable`! You could set any `Drawable` to the Image view.

Besides setting the `Drawable` through Java API, you could also using XML attribution to set the source `Drawable` for `ImageView`. See example below. Note that the shape could be either an image file (.png, .jpg, .bmp) or xml file.

Comment: But which API call is faster? `setImageDrawable` seems to be the fastest but what is with the other ones?

Answer (score 4):

Both methods are valid and achieve the same result.
In the first method you wrap your bitmap around a drawable object which is an abstraction for anything that can be drawn in a View.

The special thing about Drawables is that they let you do all kinds of operations on the graphical object they wrap around (scaling, translation, opacity etc..).

A bitmap is one kind of drawable, you can learn further about drawables here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

In the second method, you directly access the bitmap bits without any drawable related operations and simply draw the bitmap as-is on your view.

Hope this helps, cheers, Max.

Comment: So performing operations on the image is the only advantage / difference of converting to a drawable? I accepted nandeesh's answer as it is more applicable for my usage.

Comment: Yeah, essentially this is the advantage or rather application of Bitmap drawables.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
// if this is used frequently, may handle bitmaps explicitly
// to reduce the intermediate drawable object
setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bm));
}
```

maybe the difference is the mContext.getResources(), from mContext.getResources()
can get the density of the divice, so the display on sceen is different