# Is there any way that an Animation-List xml set drawable suddenly becomes a BitmapDrawable?

Tags: android, android-animation, bitmapdrawable

So i have this animation-list drawable and it is a series of images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true"> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="2000" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="2000" /> 
</animation-list>
```

Now the problem is, there are times when I would get this error and causes a force close of my app:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable
at com.example.try.drawable.AnimationClass.run(AnimationClass.java:80)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is what I have is being pointed to in the AnimationClass:

```
public void run() {
    ((AnimationDrawable) mImages.getDrawable()).start();
}
```

The mImages variable is the ones I have in my xml. I am displaying them to the user much like a splashImage. The problem is I sometimes get this error and I don't know how it really happens.

P.S.
I intentionally changed some variable names and package names, but hopefully the code is still as clear as it was for me.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you set a bitmap to `ImageView` for recycling purpose android will create new `BitmapDrawable` object

```
BitmapDrawable drawable =new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

and set it to the `ImageView`..because For recycling the `Bitmap` in the `Imageview` like..

```
drawable.getBitmap().recycle();
```

so thats why it is returning the `BitmapDrawable` object

Comment: But why doesn't the error always manifest itself when using the app and only at random times?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe didn't get what you are saying..can you explain clearly??

Comment: OP doesnt mention ImageView at all, so why do you do so?

Comment: Yes I am actually using an ImageView wherein I am setting the animation-list. What I am asking is actually why am I getting the error above wherein the BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to an AnimationDrawable where in actuality it works fine most of the time and then it crashes showing the error only sometimes. Shouldn't it crash more frequently considering your answer?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe is this exception is sometimes??

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe check this you will get clear idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001793/android-imageview-setimagebitmap-vs-setimagedrawable what they are doing internally after your image set..

Comment: @kalyanpvs what process are you talking about? when you call View.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) View doesnt change input Drawable at all

Comment: Yes the exception only happens sometimes.

Comment: @pskink you are right..sorry. this is only for ImageViews not for all views.For Views Actual Drawable will set..

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe post your code, if you have cast exception it means that you set the background of your View to BitmapDrawable, there is **NO** automatic background replacement

Comment: @pskink what you have said is correct for other views but when you set for ImageView they will change..once check this ImageView source code..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001793/android-imageview-setimagebitmap-vs-setimagedrawable

Comment: @kalyanpvs when you use ImageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable), too,  ImageView doesnt change input Drawable at all

Comment: For not ImageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable) ther you are directly set the drawable object..this is for setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) or setImageUri(Uri)

Comment: @pskink ImageView Source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ImageView.java

Comment: you said "Whenever you set a bitmap or drawable to ImageView for recycling purpose android will create new BitmapDrawable object" which is not true: only when you call setImageBitmpap(Bitmap) a new BitmapDrawable is created