# How to set opaque picture as layout background

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a full screen layout and I want to use an opaque blurry version of image or bitmap as the background.  So I need to know:

1) how to set a image/bitmap as background of a layout like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. Is there a different approach for bitmap vs. image?

2) How to make it look blurry.

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bit);
(view).setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

There is no difference between bitmap and image .. just go through this link for more details ..

[Android - ImageView: setImageBitmap VS setImageDrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001793/android-imageview-setimagebitmap-vs-setimagedrawable)