# Difference between setImageBitmap and setImageUri?

Tags: android, bitmap, uri

I am trying to load an image from a file chooser into an ImageView.

In tutorial i see it like this:

```
try {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), mImageUri);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, I just tried a simple

```
mImageView.setImageUri(mImageUri)
```

instead and it works just as well. Am I missing something here? Why are these tutorials usin such a big amount of code if it works with 1 line?

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial?

Comment: There are a lot of different tutorials that all use this approach. This is one example:
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-example/

Answer (score 3):

From [pierrotlefou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115722/pierrotlefou) answer on [Android - ImageView: setImageBitmap VS setImageDrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001793/android-imageview-setimagebitmap-vs-setimagedrawable)

---

`ImageView` has 4 APIs to specify the image. Which one to use? What is the difference?

1. setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)
2. setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
3. setImageResource(int resId)
4. setImageURI(URI uri)

`ImageView`, by the name, is used to display an image. But what is a image? A `Bitmap` is-a image, not hard to understand and we use `setImageBitmap` for that purpose. However, internally, the `ImageView` has-a `Drawable` but not a `Bitmap` and that is what `setImageDrawable` for. When you call `setImageBitmap`, internally, first the bitmap will be wrapped to `BitmapDrawable`, which IS-A `Drawable`, and then call `setImageDrawable`.

Here is the code.

```
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bm));
}
```

So, what about the 3 and 4 API?

You should already know that that are bunches of ways to create a bitmap: from a file path, from an input stream, from the Uri, or from the resource file.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String pathName)
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(Inputstream)
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resource res, int id)
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte[] data)
```

Aware of this, it is easy to understand `setImageResource`/`setImageUri` is just same as `setImageBitmap`.

To sum up, `setImageDrawable` is the primitive function other APIs rely on. The other 3 are just helper methods making you write less code.

In addition, it is very important to keep in mind that `ImageView` actually has-a `Drawable`, which not necessarily to be a `BitmapDrawable`! You could set any `Drawable` to the Image view.

Besides setting the `Drawable` through Java API, you could also using XML attribution to set the source `Drawable` for `ImageView`. See example below. Note that the shape could be either an image file (.png, .jpg, .bmp) or xml file.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162280/discussion-on-answer-by-ricky-notaro-garcia-difference-between-setimagebitmap-an).