# Why else statement is not initializing?

Tags: java, android-studio, if-statement

I want to hide Some ImageButton while making image description visible.
However else if statement is not working as intended.

OnCreate:

```
    ImageView thumbnail;
    ImageButton addImage ,removeImage;
    EditText description;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_write);

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started");

            thumbnail = findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            addImage = findViewById(R.id.addImage);
            removeImage = findViewById(R.id.removeImage);
            description = findViewById(R.id.description);


            setupToolbar();
            setupBodyEditor();
            addThumbnail();
        }
```

addThumnail:

```
  private void addThumbnail() {


    if ( thumbnail.getDrawable()== null)
    {
        addImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        removeImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        addImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        removeImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            removeImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            addImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),5);
        }
    });

    removeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            thumbnail.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    });

}
```

onActivityResult:

```
 if (requestCode== 5  && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
        {
            try {
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                thumbnail.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
 else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Image Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Tried naming variables differently but nothing worked.

Even if Thumbnail ImageView contains an image, it still shows addImage button and description is also not made visible.

Comment: I think you don't need an `else if` with the check if it is `!= null`, you already know it is not null and, thus, you can just use `else { ... }`. But that might not be the reason for your error.

Comment: I tried that too but gives same result.

Comment: Thought so... Then the reason is one or more of the methods triggered not working as desired. Is `Thumbnail` a class? Does `Thumbnail` have a `static` method `getDrawable()`? If yes, you might have trouble with capitalized variable names.

Comment: Thumbnail is an imageview.

Comment: Unrelated: learn about java naming conventions. Variable names go camelCase in Java. Your variable names look like ClassNames, and that is really confusing.

Comment: I changed all variable names to lower case but it is still behaving same.

Comment: @TajanThind changing variable names won't have an effect on the program, it just makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **setImageDrawable** in your code. ImageView is always null.

```
setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001793/android-imageview-setimagebitmap-vs-setimagedrawable

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you do not change the buttons visibilty after the image has been added (immediately). Only when the `onCreate` method is invoked the changes will be applied.

According to the [`Activity Lifecylce`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) this is only done if your `Activity` is launched (initially or after the process has been killed).

To fix your issue you will have to trigger the change of the visibility for the `addImage`, `removeImage` & `description` elements together with the setting of your thumbnail image (from inside your `onActivityResult` method).